# Python Fill up Web Form and Download

Tags: python, webforms

I am trying to fill up a web form in https://www.floridaucc.com/uccweb/downloads.aspx
and download the accordingly generated file using Python.

First I have to accept the agreement. Then I need to select the regular radio button. Then select the Debtors radio button. Then I have to select a date in mm/dd/yyyy format. And finally click the Download button.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: in what format actually do you want to download the form?

Comment: html format is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often this can be done by inspecting the request in the browser and examining the structure of a couple CURL commands. However sometimes this isn't the case. An automated web driver like [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/py) could be your best bet. Make sure, though, that your usage doesn't violate the terms of service of the site.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer with an example for selenium python?

Comment: selenium is a huge package with lots of features, and configuring it to work with a specific website requires a custom approach to the application. There are a lot of good tutorials online ([here's one](https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/)), though, and [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) are very comprehensive. good luck!